# DataView RowFilter determine if a DateTime column is greater than another DateTime column plus 6 months

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime, dataview, rowfilter

I have a dataview which has two columns.
A and B
each column has a date in it of type DateTime.

I would like to filter the dataview to only show rows where dates in A are greater than dates in B plus 6 months

A > (B+6months)

Here is what I have tried with no success.

```
DataView.RowFilter = "A > System.DateTime(B).AddMonths(6)";

DataView.RowFilter = "A > B.AddMonths(6)";
```

I appreciated any help given.

Comment: Is there a way to do this using framework 2.0 c#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not a C# expert, but I believe you can use Linq to create the DataView as follows:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable("MyTable"); // example data container

...

DataView dv = (from d in dt.AsEnumerable() where ((DateTime)d["A"]) > ((DateTime)d["B"]).AddMonths(6) select d).AsDataView();
```

Comment: I used slightly different syntax than ron tornambe's comment by it set me on the right track. Thank you for your help.